# Books on abelian varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I was wondering if there were any particular recommendations for books on abelian varieties? Especially for the algebraic side. I’m following Mumford right now and he deals with the analytic side nicely.

I’m looking for a nice introduction to Jacobians, however. Unfortunately Mumford doesn’t mention these. Preferably from an arithmetic angle, but this isn’t necessary - it’s more important that the algebraic exposition is good.

Comment: There's Milne, this book for Complex Abelian Varieties https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-06307-1, there's Polishchuk's (book not recommended), and there's also many course pages online. Personally, I think the second one I mentioned has a good section on Jacobians.

Comment: @AHappyMathematician Thank you! Thanks also to those who tagged this as a duplicate - it did not come up on my search unfortunately.